# How do i center the nav for smartphone devices

Tags: html, css, navbar

I created a nav bar that I put on the right side of the screen as you can see from the code below

```css
.navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  right: 4%;
  top: 3%;
}

.navbar li {
  float: right;
}

.navbar li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.navbar li a:hover {
  color: darkgrey;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="navbar">
    <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I would like to center it for phones and i have tried to just adjust with the percentage but for different devices the result is different.

I would like to know if there is a way to center the navbar for smartophone devices that would be correctly centered for all  smartphone's screen sizes

Comment: Use flexbox or grid to center. Like with flex, you can do: display: flex; justify-content: center; width: 100%.

Comment: Making use of @Developer 's comment. You can also implement media queries e.g.
`@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) { /* Your styles*/ }`
You can change the screen size dimensions according to you specifications

Comment: @imran.ke Read the question please. Try to understand his requirements.

Comment: @giorgio_stringari did flexbox resolve your issue?

Comment: it didn't position it in the center, thank you anyways

Comment: @giorgiostringari So, should I write answer??

Answer (score 0):

1. You could use `media`:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar {
    position: static;
    right: auto;
    top: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .navbar li {
    float: none;
  }
  
  .navbar li a {
    padding: 14px 30px;
  }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't put it in the center perfectly it seems like it is more to the left